# updates failing

Tags: updates, update-manager

I go to update but I get this error

```
  W:GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 977C43A8BA684223,  
  W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
  W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
  W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
  E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

sources.list:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Comment: can you include the content of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: @younes I just updated it

Comment: i cant't  see where the ppa mentioned in this line `http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages` is included, this is a result of apt-get update , right?

Comment: @younes, Yes, I am no longer using it. I believe it was from when I was going to try the UbuntuTV distro (I misread the requirement for unity 2d)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:u2t/bleedingedge` it will add the ppa so it will become visible, then execute this command `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:u2t/bleedingedge` to remove it correctly then update your question with the output of `sudo apt-get update`

use this

```
wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:ownCloud:community/xUbuntu_14.04/Release.key
sudo apt-key add - < Release.key
```

and report back the changes,
this last two lines download the GPG key and add it to the apt key store

Comment: when running the update I get an error: W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 977C43A8BA684223

Comment: good, now we have narrowed down errors, i just want to know what did you export from opensuse, so that we can fix this last error

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure. Either has to do with owncloud or ubuntutv. Those are the only two things that were over my head during installation

Comment: i updated my answer